# UIDocumentBrowserViewController get file data

Tags: ios, uidocumentbrowservc

when i use UIDocumentBrowserViewController, and get file's documentURL ,like" file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8F45C0E0-446B-4C89-A7AB-95E148BE0F41/Documents/sd1513175706_2.MP4 ", and i use [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile] to get data, but it's not work. what's the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `startAccessingSecurityScopedResource` on that URL to consume the sandbox extension vended to you by the document browser. Don’t forget to call stopAccessing once you are done in order not to leak kernel resources.